# Is sugar a necessary ingredient to feed yeast?

Tags: baking, bread, dough, ingredients

I consider myself a reasonably successful baker, including making my own bread dough from scratch. Lately, when searching for some new and different recipes,  I notice not all dough recipes call for sugar, or any form of sugar. I was always taught that sugar is food and life for yeast and crucial for a proper rise?  What would be the reason for this omission?

Comment: You might also be interested in the answers to this question https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/45587

Answer (score 15):

The answer is that there are a range of (natural) sugars in the flour and a range of sugars that can be generated by the yeast by breaking down the starches and other carbohydrates in flour. Yeast are a hardy organism and can metabolize many different carbohydrates to produce sugars for successful growth.

Carbohydrates are chemical compounds composed of Carbon, Hydrogen and Oxygen. Usually carbohydrates come in a monomer (single molecule) form such as glucose or they come in dimer (2 molecules joined together) such as sucrose (sugar; made up of a glucose molecule and a fructose molecule), after this they form short chains known as oligomers and then polymers. The polymers come in a huge variety, many of which we consume on a regular basis and know as "starch". Yeasts and many other organisms (including ourselves) can break down starches into their individual monomers - and derive energy from these monomers, just as they would from the monomers themselves.

There are also alternate sources of sugars in many recipes: Some recipes ask for <strike>milk - it contains some sugars too - you have probably heard of lactose; it's a type of sugar that yeast will happily metabolize</strike> - it turns out this isn't the case - lactose is a sugar, but, you need specially modified yeast for them to able to metabolize lactose. The milk provides some fat and protein in bread making. Many grains contain sugars in forms other than starch too - whole wheat grains contain things like [raffinose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raffinose), which the yeast can use for growth.

There's a nice relatively simple explanation of yeast metabolism [here](http://www.fao.org/3/x0560e/x0560e08.htm) that is mostly targeted at production of alcoholic products - but the same mechanisms apply to bread making, which is often carried out with the same organisms.

Note that sour-dough loaves use a range of bacteria and yeasts that ferment sugars to produce the distinctive lactic acid sour taste. The mechanisms by which they do this are quite diverse, but they are equally adept at breaking down sources of sugar into simple, metabolisable sugars.

Comment: Carbohydrates in flour: https://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/food/flour/carbohydrate Yeast contains enzymes that break these down into simple sugars, like glucose, that provide food energy. A few more types of flour and carb content: https://www.leaf.tv/articles/how-many-carbs-are-in-flour/ Sugar or glucose is a nice additive in that it provides an almost immediate source of food energy. You get CO2 faster from simple sugars.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Yes. Carbohydrates is a term that covers quite a range of things though - from simple sugars to starches, cellulose, lignins etc. Not all of these are metabolisable by yeasts in general

Comment: Lignin is not usually considered a carb. It's got some really odd structures to it;https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lignin  I'm generally agreeing with you. just thought a little expansion would be nice, especially as most folk don't know the differences between sugars, carbohydrates, digestible or not, and fiber. Incidentally, lignin is usually classed as a dietary fiber: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dietary_fiber IIRC, it's what they used to put in that super high fiber bread; AKA sawdust.

Comment: That answer makes sense. Thanks for taking the time for such a thorough explanation!

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - you are correct. I'll expand the answer later.

Comment: @Hutchette - if you like the answer, please mark it accepted, it's one of the ways the site metrics float the answers so that the good ones rise to the top. Thanks.

Comment: Yeast (unless genetically modified) cannot break down lactose (or even galactose).  This is the basis for sweet (formerly milk) stouts, e.g.

Comment: @wumpusD'00m - huh, you are quite right. I need to brush up on my yeast metabolism. I'll edit that in.

Comment: @bob1  Yeast metabolism was SO long ago. I only remembered the lignin thing because I darn near flunked the course over not being able to draw the structures.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - indeed, around 20 y for me. The odd thing is I am now just starting to use yeast for some molecular biology, so I should probably re-learn it a bit. Having said that I'm using pretty standard lab strains and just need them to grow on regular media, which were worked out long ago.

Answer (score 4):

Grains such as wheat are little self-contained capsules of everything needed to grow a plant (up until its first leaves, after which it can pull from its environment).

Plants, like animals and fungus such as yeast, require a source of energy for its cells to function.  That energy source is the carbon-hydrogen bond in sugars.  A seed needs sugars to grow into a plant.  Unfortunately, that same sugar is used by other things like years, for the same reasons, so it's not a survival mechanism to store the sugars in the seed directly.  Instead, they're stored in long chains called starches, together with the mechanisms for converting those starches back into sugars (enzymes called "amylases").  When the seed finds itself in the right conditions -- the right temperature, the right amount of ambient moisture -- the amylases get activated, the starches are converted to sugars, and the seed begins to grow.

We take these seeds, grind them into a powder, and remove some of the unwanted bits leaving mostly the starches and some proteins like gluten and the amylases.  We then add the same conditions for sprouting the seed -- warmth and water -- and the enzymes go to work splitting the starches into sugars.  We add fungus (yeast) that eats the sugars and emit carbon dioxide as a byproduct, and we end up with bread.

The lesson is that all seeds come with at least enough enzyme to turn all of their starch into sugar because that's the whole point of a seed.  Recipes add extra sugar to "feed" yeast to speed the process up (I want it now!) and to make the final product sweeter because people like sweet things.

Comment: `The lesson is that all seeds come with at least enough enzyme to turn all of their starch into sugar because that's the whole point of a seed` is probably the most important observation here :) please double check your text for typos like years <> yeasts